# Copy files from sub folders

Tags: excel, vba

[image]

[image]

From Rows 5 to 204
Column B is just numbering the rows
In column C Have a list of pdf file names (these are pdf certs)
I run a bit of code and it filters the unique values from column C to column E and sorts A-Z
Column G has the formula `=IF(E5="","",LEFT(E5,2))` to get the file index No.
Column H has the formula `=IF(E5="","",VLOOKUP(G5+0,$I$5:$J$11,2,FALSE))` to get the file path for the folders where the certs are
Columns I & J are the Lookup table.

I put together code which will loop down the list of cert numbers in column E and then offset(0,3) to column H where the folder file-path for that cert is. It then goes to that folder copies that particular file into a folder on my desktop, then carries on down the list in column E offsetting to the file-path until it reaches the end of the cert numbers in column E, any files that are missing it highlights in red.

```vb
Sub CopyCerts() 'copying certs
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Dim R As Range
    Set R = Range("E5:E204")
    Dim SourcePath As String, DestPath As String, FName As String, FileExists As String
    DestPath = "C:\Users\GaryBaker\Desktop\Certs\" 'folder to copy to
    
    For Each R In Range("E5", Range("E" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)) 'Check file name in each used cell in column E
        R.Offset(0, 3).Activate
        SourcePath = ActiveCell.Value
        FileExists = Dir(SourcePath & R.Value & ".pdf") 'checking if the cert exists
        FName = Dir(SourcePath & R.Value & ".pdf") 'name of file from list in (E5:E)
        If FileExists = "" Then 'If the file does not exist highlight in red, else copy
            ActiveCell.Offset(0, -3).Font.Color = vbRed 'Highlight any Cert Nos. in range E that are missing
        Else
            FileCopy SourcePath & FName, DestPath & FName 'Copy the file
        End If
        Do While FName <> "" 'Loop while files found
            FName = Dir() 'Search the next file
        Loop
    Next
    MsgBox ("files copied")
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

I need to modify the code so it will search the subfolders of each main folder as well.

I had several attempts to cobble together some code. I keep getting errors “For without Next”, “Block if without end if”, End if without Block if” etc.

```vb
Sub CopyCertsSubFolders() 'copying certs
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Dim R As Range
    Set R = Range("E5:E204")
    Dim SourcePath As String, DestPath As String, FName As String, FileExists As String, FSO As Object, fld As Object, FSOFile As Object, fsoFol As Object
    DestPath = "C:\Users\GaryBaker\Desktop\Certs\" 'folder to copy to
    
    If Right(SourcePath, 1) <> "\" Then
        SourcePath = SourcePath & "\"
    End If
    
    Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set fld = FSO.GetFolder(SourcePath)
    If FSO.FolderExists(fld) Then
    End If
    'For Each fsoFol In FSO.GetFolder(SourcePath).subfolders
    'For Each FSOFile In fsoFol.Files
    
    For Each R In Range("E5", Range("E" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)) 'Check file name in each used cell in column E
        R.Offset(0, 3).Activate
        SourcePath = ActiveCell.Value
        FileExists = Dir(SourcePath & subfolders & R.Value & ".pdf") 'checking if the cert exists in folders & sub-folders
        FName = Dir(SourcePath & subfolders & R.Value & ".pdf") 'name of file from list in (E5:E)
    
        If FileExists = "" Then 'If the file does not exist highlight in red, else copy
            ActiveCell.Offset(0, -3).Font.Color = vbRed 'Highlight any Cert Nos. in range E that are missing
        Else
            FileCopy SourcePath & FName, DestPath & FName 'Copy the file
        End If
                
        Do While FName <> "" 'Loop while files found
            FName = Dir() 'Search the next file
        Loop
    Next
    MsgBox ("files copied")
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This function will return the first matching file path, given a folder to start in and an exact or partial file name (use * as wildcard if required).

```vb
'Find the first file in `startFolder` (or subfolders of that location) which
'  matches `filePattern`
Function MatchFirstFile(startFolder As String, filePattern As String) As String
    Dim colSub As New Collection, f, fld
    colSub.Add startFolder
    Do While colSub.Count > 0
        fld = colSub(1)
        colSub.Remove 1
        f = Dir(fld, vbDirectory)
        Do While Len(f) > 0
            If GetAttr(fld & f) = vbDirectory Then
                If f <> "." And f <> ".." Then 'ignore parent and current folders
                    colSub.Add fld & f & "\"
                End If
            Else
                Debug.Print "File: " & fld & f   'EDIT
                If UCase(f) Like UCase(filePattern) Then
                    MatchFirstFile = fld & f  '###### FIXED
                    Exit Function
                End If
            End If
            f = Dir()
        Loop
    Loop
End Function
```

You can try modifying your code to call the function:

```vb
Dim ws As Worksheet, foundFile

Set ws = ActiveSheet

For Each R In ws.Range("E5", ws.Range("E" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)).Cells
    
    foundFile = MatchFirstFile(R.Offset(0, 3).Value, R.Value & ".pdf") 'call the function
                                                                       'for first match
    
    If Len(foundFile) = 0 Then
        R.Offset(0, 3).Font.Color = vbRed 'Highlight any Cert Nos. in range E that are missing
    Else
        FileCopy foundFile, DestPath & R.Value & ".pdf" 'Copy the file
    End If
    
Next R
```

Comment: Hi Tim Thanks for helping me, it is really appreciated. It looks like its working there are no errors, but it doesn't find any of the files at all. Posting code in case I have something wrong.

Comment: Hi Tim. I have been doing some testing and set up a folder with 8 pdf certs in it, with matching numbers in my Range R ("E5 to E204"). I counted the loops by stepping through the code. It looped 8 times, it seems it is finding the folder & going through the files OK but does not match them to the names in my list.

Comment: Added a `Debug.Print` to the function above - see what output that gives you.  Do you see any files listed?

Comment: Hi Tim
Thanks for getting back to me, apologies this is being a problem
I ran the code and nothing happened it just ran as if it was working right through to the message box “Files Copied”, it didn’t print anything at all.
I then stepped through your code looking for 8 Pdf files in the parent folder (Which I know are in there), it looped through all 8 as if it had found them, then it started to loop through the Else Debug.Print "File: " & fld & f   'EDIT. Part of the code.

Comment: When stepping through the code it gets as far as this line [If f <> "." And f <> ".." Then] 'ignore parent and current folders, missing out the next line [colSub.Add fld & f & "\"] and goes straight to [End If]
I changed the number of files it was looking for in column E to 2 but it looped through the first part of your function 6 times as above, then it moved onto the else [Debug.print] part of your function.

Comment: OK Tim
Test folder with two Pdf files in it and no subfolders and matching numbers in column E on my spreadsheet.

Comment: This is what happens
1. It steps through the CopyCertsSubfolder code & calls the Function MatchFirstFile
2. It loops through the first part of the function twice
3. It then loops through the debug part of the Function once
4. It then goes to [If Len(foundFile) = 0 Then] line in the CopyCertsSubfolder code
5. Then [R.Font.Color = vbRed] 'Highlight any Cert Nos. in range E that are missing line
6. Then [End If]
7. Then [Next R] and repeats as above.
8. Then goes on to the end of the sub

Comment: Note the values in column E are formatted as text as some of the keep converting into a date, will that make a difference to your code.

Comment: Pretty difficult for me to debug a problem without your actual file structure.  Note that the Immediate window only shows the last 200 lines output, so you may not be seeing all of the relevant info there....

Comment: It may be some problem with the format of the filenames as you note.  Try using a test file with a simpler name (eg. "Test.pdf") and see if that get found.

Comment: Thanks Tim I have, tried with the unique No. as test1.pdf With the pdf file named as test1 and it didn’t work. I also tried with the unique No. as test1 which also didn’t work. I have now posted the results from your debug print code; it had been deleted as I had posted it incorrectly.

Comment: Hi Tim, I can't seem to post this so it is neat & tidy so I will add it to a couple of comments. I ran a new test with your debug code this time looking for these numbers 01-5709, 02-5175, 03-11029, 03-11032
In my test folder only

Comment: Here are the results part 1
File: L:\PURCHASING\QC Document Controller\Test\01-5079.pdf
File: L:\PURCHASING\QC Document Controller\Test\02-5175.pdf
File: L:\PURCHASING\QC Document Controller\Test\03-11029.pdf
File: L:\PURCHASING\QC Document Controller\Test\03-11032.pdf
File: L:\PURCHASING\QC Document Controller\Test\01-5079.pdf
File: L:\PURCHASING\QC Document Controller\Test\02-5175.pdf

Comment: Here are the results part 2
File: L:\PURCHASING\QC Document Controller\Test\01-5079.pdf
File: L:\PURCHASING\QC Document Controller\Test\02-5175.pdf
File: L:\PURCHASING\QC Document Controller\Test\03-11029.pdf
File: L:\PURCHASING\QC Document Controller\Test\01-5079.pdf
File: L:\PURCHASING\QC Document Controller\Test\02-5175.pdf
File: L:\PURCHASING\QC Document Controller\Test\03-11029.pdf
File: L:\PURCHASING\QC Document Controller\Test\03-11032.pdf

Comment: So sorry I had the return value line for the function returning to the wrong variable... Should be `MatchFirstFile = fld & f`   BTW if you use `Option Explicit` that would have been flagged up right away as a problem (serves me right for editing the code in the browser after pasting)

Comment: Tim, no need for any apology I am extremely grateful for your help and patience. I have pressed the accept tick  is there anything else I need to do. Gary

Comment: Is it working now?

Comment: Working Great Tim, I am extremely grateful for your help and patience. I have pressed the accept tick is there anything else I need to do. Gary

Comment: No you're all set.  Good to hear it's working.

Answer (score 0):

Tim As comment the code does not find or copy any files. Please see the code below

```
    Sub CopyCertsSubFolders() 'copying certs
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim R As Range
Set R = Range("E5:E204")
Dim ws As Worksheet, foundFile
Set ws = ActiveSheet
DestPath = "C:\Users\GaryBaker\Desktop\Certs\" 'folder to copy to

For Each R In ws.Range("E5", ws.Range("E" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)).Cells
    foundFile = MatchFirstFile(R.Offset(0, 3).Value, R.Value & ".pdf") 'call the function 'for first match
        If Len(foundFile) = 0 Then
            R.Font.Color = vbRed 'Highlight any Cert Nos. in range E that are missing
        Else
    FileCopy foundFile, DestPath & R.Value & ".pdf" 'Copy the file
End If

Next R
MsgBox ("files copied")

 Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

And Below

```
'Find the first file in `startFolder` (or subfolders of that location) which
'  matches `filePattern`
Function MatchFirstFile(startFolder As String, filePattern As String) As String
    Dim colSub As New Collection, f, fld
    colSub.Add startFolder
    Do While colSub.Count > 0
        fld = colSub(1)
        colSub.Remove 1
        f = Dir(fld, vbDirectory)
        Do While Len(f) > 0
            If GetAttr(fld & f) = vbDirectory Then
                If f <> "." And f <> ".." Then 'ignore parent and current folders
                    colSub.Add fld & f & "\"
                End If
            Else
                If UCase(f) Like UCase(filePattern) Then
                    MatchFile = fld & f
                    Exit Function
                End If
            End If
            f = Dir()
        Loop
    Loop
End Function
```

Apologies Tim I had my post deleted, I put it in the wrong place, I have worked out how to use Debug.Print There was 199 lines as below in the intermediate window up to 07-1176.pdf

1. File: L:\MATERIALS\Material Certification\07-PAINT & COATING\07-0978.pdf
2. File: L:\MATERIALS\Material Certification\07-PAINT & COATING\07-0979.pdf
3. File: L:\MATERIALS\Material Certification\07-PAINT & COATING\07-0980.pdf
4. File: L:\MATERIALS\Material Certification\07-PAINT & COATING\07-0981.pdf
5. File: L:\MATERIALS\Material Certification\07-PAINT & COATING\07-0982.pdf
6. File: L:\MATERIALS\Material Certification\07-PAINT & COATING\07-0983.pdf
7. File: L:\MATERIALS\Material Certification\07-PAINT & COATING\07-0984.pdf
8. File: L:\MATERIALS\Material Certification\07-PAINT & COATING\07-0985.pdf
9. File: L:\MATERIALS\Material Certification\07-PAINT & COATING\07-0986.pdf
10. File: L:\MATERIALS\Material Certification\07-PAINT & COATING\07-0987.pdf
11. File: L:\MATERIALS\Material Certification\07-PAINT & COATING\07-0988.pdf
12. File: L:\MATERIALS\Material Certification\07-PAINT & COATING\07-0989.pdf
13. File: L:\MATERIALS\Material Certification\07-PAINT & COATING\07-0990.pdf
14. File: L:\MATERIALS\Material Certification\07-PAINT & COATING\07-0991.pdf
15. File: L:\MATERIALS\Material Certification\07-PAINT & COATING\07-0992.pdf

Please find image of the search I carried out using your debug code
[Search screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a3oVo.png)

Hi Tim, thanks for all your help. I ran a new test with your debug code this time looking for these numbers 01-5709, 02-5175, 03-11029, 03-11032 In my test folder only

Here are the results

1. File: L:\PURCHASING\QC Document Controller\Test\01-5079.pdf
2. File: L:\PURCHASING\QC Document Controller\Test\02-5175.pdf
3. File: L:\PURCHASING\QC Document Controller\Test\03-11029.pdf
4. File: L:\PURCHASING\QC Document Controller\Test\03-11032.pdf
5. File: L:\PURCHASING\QC Document Controller\Test\01-5079.pdf
6. File: L:\PURCHASING\QC Document Controller\Test\02-5175.pdf
7. File: L:\PURCHASING\QC Document Controller\Test\01-5079.pdf
8. File: L:\PURCHASING\QC Document Controller\Test\02-5175.pdf
9. File: L:\PURCHASING\QC Document Controller\Test\03-11029.pdf
10. File: L:\PURCHASING\QC Document Controller\Test\01-5079.pdf
11. File: L:\PURCHASING\QC Document Controller\Test\02-5175.pdf
12. File: L:\PURCHASING\QC Document Controller\Test\03-11029.pdf
13. File: L:\PURCHASING\QC Document Controller\Test\03-11032.pdf
    [Screen shot of search](https://i.stack.imgur.com/au8PP.png)